# Copying database from assets with SQLiteAssetHelper

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

When I'm trying to open my database in android api level 8 with Sqliteassethelper, my application crashing with this error cat log:

```
01-10 13:08:15.063      321-321/com.omidgraphic.naghshekhial E/SQLiteAssetHelper﹕ Couldn't open database.sqlite for writing (will try read-only):
    com.omidgraphic.naghshekhial.lib.SQLiteAssetHelper$SQLiteAssetException: Unable to write /data/data/com.omidgraphic.naghshekhial/databases/database.sqlite to data directory
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.readAsset(Native Method)
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.access$700(AssetManager.java:36)
            at android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream.read(AssetManager.java:571)
            at com.omidgraphic.naghshekhial.lib.Utils.writeExtractedFileToDisk(Utils.java:45)
            at com.omidgraphic.naghshekhial.lib.SQLiteAssetHelper.copyDatabaseFromAssets(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:459)
            at com.omidgraphic.naghshekhial.lib.SQLiteAssetHelper.createOrOpenDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:402)
            at com.omidgraphic.naghshekhial.lib.SQLiteAssetHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:176)
            at com.omidgraphic.naghshekhial.lib.SQLiteAssetHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:257)
```

What is the problem?

it's activity code:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_activity);
        Data dt;
        dt= new Data(this);

    }
}
```

it's data:

```
public class Data extends com.omidgraphic.naghshekhial.lib.SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME    = "database.sqlite";
    private static final int    DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private Context        context;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    public Data(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
        db();
    }
```

ISN'T ABOUT THE SIZE OF DATABASE? `4.34 MB (4,554,752 bytes)`

Comment: do u hv proper permissions?

Comment: Size of my database is `4.53 MB (4,751,360 bytes)`

Comment: what permissions? it's working on `huawei y530` without any problem but in some devices and also emulators get crash

Comment: what you are trying to do?

Comment: Trying to copy a database that stored in assets folder into database folder of my application `data` folder and then reading data from it.

Comment: try this code :https://github.com/mtetno/code-snippet/blob/master/AssetDatabaseOpenHelper.java

Comment: not working too, isn't about the size of database ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Using a unzipped version of the database worked.